# Object Operator Conflicting with Visual Studio

Tags: php, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, operators

I am attempting to use the php object operator (->) as well as create an associative array using (=>) in an aspx file, when I use code that previously has worked standalone it causes all sorts of issues in Visual Studio. Right now the code will not compile fully and any lines of code following a -> are displayed as text on my webpage. Here is a sample of my code (using different data for security reasons).

```
<?php
$pac6_1 = new C_PhpAutocomplete('Laboratory');
$pac6_2 = new C_PhpAutocomplete('Project');
$pac6_3 = new C_PhpAutocomplete('Mix Design');

$pac6_1->set_child($pac6_2, 'projectData');
$pac6_2->set_child($pac6_3, 'mixData');

$pac6_1->display('SELECT');
$pac6_2->display();
$pac6_3->display();
?>
```

Comment: PHP code works in VB? I didn't even know that was possible.

Comment: my bad, I mean it is in the .aspx file, sorry for the confusion